# convert CDA XML to PDF without *TeX?

Tags: pdf, xml, latex

Apologies for the hyper-specificity of my requirements, but they are what they are ...

## summary

The box I'm using runs Debian. I want to render a [Clinical Document Architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clinical_Document_Architecture) *(CDA)* document to PDF to send as an attachment. Chrome fails utterly, Firefox *almost* succeeds, and `xmlto` wants TeX (which has in past been a problem install on this box). Got an alternative?

## details

A CDA document is basically a `zip`ed filetree containing XML, styling, and images. In my case, the filetree is like

```
$ find | sort # edited for brevity and PII
.
./MachineReadable_XDMFormat
./MachineReadable_XDMFormat/HTML
./MachineReadable_XDMFormat/HTML/IMAGES
# list of PNGs omitted
./MachineReadable_XDMFormat/HTML/STYLE
./MachineReadable_XDMFormat/HTML/STYLE/colors.css
./MachineReadable_XDMFormat/HTML/STYLE/main.css
./MachineReadable_XDMFormat/IHE_XDM
./MachineReadable_XDMFormat/IHE_XDM/my_ID
./MachineReadable_XDMFormat/IHE_XDM/my_ID/DOC0001.XML   # see note#=1
./MachineReadable_XDMFormat/IHE_XDM/my_ID/METADATA.XML
./MachineReadable_XDMFormat/IHE_XDM/my_ID/STYLE.XSL
./MachineReadable_XDMFormat/INDEX.HTM                   # see note#=2
./MachineReadable_XDMFormat/README.TXT                  # see note#=3
./MachineReadable_XDMFormat/Summary.pdf                 # see note#=4
```

Notes:

1. `DOC0001.XML` is the data payload: all other files are just decoration.
2. `INDEX.HTM` is not a rendering of `DOC0001.XML`; it's an entirely separate page with a link to `DOC0001.XML` (*et al*) plus some explanatory text.
3. `README.TXT` is not much: just the information above, plus how to `unzip` a file.
4. So why doesn't `Summary.pdf` solve my problem? Unfortunately, this PDF contains a *lot* of extraneous information, because `.../DOC0001.XML` (which contains the actual data) contains lots items that aren't relevant to the consumer. I can edit that XML without difficulty, and even render the edited XML (see section=`Firefox` below), but I can't convert that edited XML into a PDF ... hence my question.

### tried and failed

#### Chrome

I have Chrome (aka `google-chrome-stable`) version=60.0.3112.90 (which I believe is currently-up-to-date for Debian version=8.9, which I believe is current Debian stable). When I'm in that and do

1. `Ctrl-o`
2. give the fully-qualified path to `.../MachineReadable_XDMFormat/IHE_XDM/my_ID/DOC0001.XML`

Chrome does absolutely nothing: no error, but also a completely blank page/tab. Similarly if I

1. `Ctrl-o`
2. give the fully-qualified path to `.../MachineReadable_XDMFormat/INDEX.HTM`
3. follow the link to `DOC0001.XML`

Chrome renders `INDEX.HTM` appropriately, but fails as previously on `DOC0001.XML`.

#### Firefox

I have Firefox version=54.0 (which I believe is currently-up-to-date for Debian version=8.9, which I believe is current Debian stable). When I'm in that and do

1. `Ctrl-o`
2. give the fully-qualified path to `.../MachineReadable_XDMFormat/IHE_XDM/my_ID/DOC0001.XML`

Firefox renders the the document appropriately/nicely. Hence I thought I could use the usual Firefox `Print to File` functionality to print this ... but it fails, since it tries to print the rather long `DOC0001.XML` as 4 pages:

1. 1st has buncha short sections
2. 2nd has just header=`Results`, and no other text. In the XML, this is the `<section>` containing all the real data (as `<item>`s).
3. 3rd attempts to print *all* the real data. Unfortunately, there is far more data than can print on 1 page; instead of handling that case, `Print to File` just truncates the single page `:-(`
4. 4th has some metadata, and most of the "information" from `INDEX.HTM`.

#### xmlto

`xmlto` (from Debian package of same name) tries, but

1. It wants to run FO, for which it wants TeX, which is locally a problem (see section=`internal` below).
2. From its error message (below), I'm not even sure `xmlto` will render this XML appropriately, since this (CDA) document's root ∉ `{appendix article bibliography book chapter colophon dedication glossary index part preface qandaset refentry reference sect1 section set setindex}`.

What I tried:

```
me@it:~ $ pushd /path/to/CDA/

me@it:/path/to/CDA $ ls -al
> drwxr-xr-x 4 me      me         4096 Jul 21 10:38 MachineReadable_XDMFormat
> -rw-r--r-- 1 me      me      1075851 Jul 21 13:35 Summary.pdf

me@it:/path/to/CDA $ date ; xmlto pdf ./MachineReadable_XDMFormat/IHE_XDM/my_ID/DOC0001.XML ; date
> Wed Aug  2 15:03:17 MST 2017
> xmlto: /path/to/CDA/MachineReadable_XDMFormat/IHE_XDM/my_ID/DOC0001.XML does not validate (status 3)
> xmlto: Fix document syntax or use --skip-validation option
> validity error : no DTD found!
...

me@it:/path/to/CDA $ date ; find ./ -type f | fgrep -ie 'dtd' | wcl
> Wed Aug  2 15:04:10 MST 2017
> 0

me@it:/path/to/CDA $ date ; xmlto --skip-validation pdf ./MachineReadable_XDMFormat/IHE_XDM/my_ID/DOC0001.XML ; date
> Wed Aug  2 15:04:32 MST 2017
> ERROR: Document root element for FO output must be one of the following elements: appendix article bibliography book chapter colophon dedication glossary index part preface qandaset refentry reference sect1 section set setindex
> PassiveTeX is needed for this format, but it is not installed. Please install the passivetex package.
> Wed Aug  2 15:04:33 MST 2017

# Note PassiveTeX is a *TeX package

me@it:/path/to/CDA $ date ; xmlto --with-fop --skip-validation pdf ./MachineReadable_XDMFormat/IHE_XDM/my_ID/DOC0001.XML ; date
> Wed Aug  2 15:12:39 MST 2017
> ERROR: Document root element for FO output must be one of the following elements: appendix article bibliography book chapter colophon dedication glossary index part preface qandaset refentry reference sect1 section set setindex
> [Fatal Error] :-1:-1: Premature end of file.
> Exception
> org.apache.fop.apps.FOPException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; Premature end of file.
> javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; Premature end of file.
>
> /tmp/xmlto.SEzLdk
> Wed Aug  2 15:12:41 MST 2017
```

### constraints

#### external

1. The Big Faceless Org with the information encoded in the CDA document provides that, period. Since CDA seems to be a standard format for interchange of information in its domain, this seems not unreasonable.
2. The folks who want the information encoded in the CDA document can consume faxes, or PDF via email, but nothing more sophisticated.
3. I don't have ready access to a fax machine.

#### internal

I.e., constraints on my side:

1. I'm running Debian version=8.9 ...
2. ... on a box with not quite enough free disk space, or perhaps not correctly allocated disk space. Probably as a result, ...
3. ... the last time I attempted to install `texlive`, (IIRC) it abended due to lack of space. This may simply be due to insufficient space allocated on my `/` partition, which is actually a partition for everything that is not `{/boot, /home, /swap}`. Details:

   ```
   # I tweak the header, but the data comes from ...
   me@it:~ $ df --human-readable | fgrep -ve 'Filesystem' | sort --key=2 --reverse --sort=human-numeric
   Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
   /dev/mapper/LVM2_crypt-home  322G  304G   19G  95% /home
   /dev/dm-2                     20G   18G  891M  96% /
   tmpfs                        1.6G  1.3M  1.6G   1% /run/shm
   /dev/sda3                    477M   73M  375M  17% /boot
   # ... rest are fake filesystems like `/dev`

   # Notes on `lsblk`:
   # `sda1` == pre-installed Windows system drive
   # `sda2` == pre-installed Windows apps drive
   # Both are whackable, but I lack the time to reallocate the space
   # (and possibly reinstall after unforeseen/disastrous failure).

   me@it:~ $ lsblk
   NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
   sda                     8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk
   ├─sda1                  8:1    0  16.6G  0 part
   ├─sda2                  8:2    0  97.7G  0 part
   ├─sda3                  8:3    0   500M  0 part  /boot
   └─sda5                  8:5    0   351G  0 part
     └─LVM2_crypt        254:0    0   351G  0 crypt
       ├─LVM2_crypt-swap 254:1    0   3.9G  0 lvm
       ├─LVM2_crypt-root 254:2    0    20G  0 lvm   /
       └─LVM2_crypt-home 254:3    0 327.1G  0 lvm   /home
   sr0                    11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
   ```

Comment: i was going to ask "why not just install tex?" but you really don't have enough disk space.  and your /home is nearly full too so symlink kludgery wont help.   can you add more disk to that machine, to extend LVM2_crypt and then LVM2_crypt-home?   BTW, it's generally recommended not to let filesystems get to 95+% full - the performance of most filesystems suffer quite badly when they get that close to being full.  And it's always bad if the rootfs fills up - especially when /var and /tmp are on it.

Comment: if you don't use the windows partitions at all, you could add sda1 to LVM2_crypt-root and sda2 to LVM2_crypt-home (optionally resizing them first for a more optimal split, say +30G for / and the rest for /home).   BTW, if there's a chance you might use them in future or need to restore the system to how it was out-of-the-box for any reason, it might be worthwhile using clonezilla to clone sda1 & sda2 to a USB stick first.